# Cannot start maven service - Class not found #

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

Ok...for the first time in my life as a Developer I have no Idea how to fix this error.

I'm having issues with Maven commands and Intellij.

(IMPORTANT)

**All maven commands on local project isn't working and returns the error:**

`cannot find or load main class #, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: #`

Detail for the "#" on the error message.

My pom.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>garantia.safra</groupId>
    <artifactId>gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gateway</name>
    <description>description</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <start-class>garantia.safra.gateway.GatewayApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwd</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried to delete .m2/repository folder but it didn't work.

I tried to 'Settings > Build, execution, deployment > Build Tools > maven > Importing' and set the import as 'project JDK' but it didnt work. (I'm using JDK 11, and it was working before)

I tried to update the maven repositories by Intellij (remote and local) and now I have a error from remote repository (can't find any imported package classes)

The only thing I did that solve it once, was recreate the project as a new one and add all the classes and pom.xml, but when I added my configuration files it broke again.

I'm using a proxy from production (.maven/jvm.config)

```
# -Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy_host>
# -Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxy_port>
# -Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxy_host>
# -Dhttps.proxyPort=<proxy_port>
```

But the lines are all commented right?

And application.properties:

```
server.address=0.0.0.0
```

So...This is being a very anoying problem, and I'm lack of ideas. Maybe I'm gonna try to recreate the project AGAIN and reimport each file to see which is the broken one, but if someone had this issue before and fixed it...how?

Comment: Does it work outside of the IDE from the command line Maven?

Comment: no, I tried it too, same error. But for some reason the command worked if I added it as a build command on intellij...well worked until I updated the pom.xml.

Comment: Try to empty or delete `.maven/jvm.config` file, it looks like it's loaded directly and has no syntax for commenting.

Comment: CrazyCoder....almost 3 weeks...you saved me. I search before to see if there was a syntax for commenting, and I found something about the '#' but I was in a hurry and 
 didn't check another sources...Please, add your answer and I'll mark as soution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty or delete `.maven/jvm.config` file, it's loaded directly and added to the command line, the comments syntax is not supported.

Comment: Again..you saved me.